# Google map styled version - labels have stroke effect even after setting visibility off

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-styling

I have a custom theme json for styling Google map. After applying the styles, the labels become blurred with stroke effect.

**I want to disable the stroke effect for labels!!!**

Tried setting visibility off for **labels.text.stroke** like below:

```
{
    "featureType": "poi.attraction",
    "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
    "stylers": [
        {
            "visibility": "off"
        }
    ]
}
```

It doesn't work. The labels still have stroke for all POIs

The same json when I import in **[mapstyle.withgoogle.com](https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/)** It works, has no stroke effect :-/

Use this [JSFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/guna_sekaran/rapbck5w/11/) to reproduce !!!

> Here's the JSON Im using:

```
[
    {
      "elementType": "geometry",
      "stylers": [
        {
          "color": "#3e3e3e"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
      "stylers": [
        {
          "visibility": "off"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "elementType": "labels.icon",
      "stylers": [
        {
          "visibility": "off"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "elementType": "labels.text",
      "stylers": [
        {
          "color": "#808080"
        },
        {
          "visibility": "on"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
      "stylers": [
        {
          "visibility": "off"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "administrative.land_parcel",
      "stylers": [
        {
          "visibility": "off"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "landscape.man_made",
      "elementType": "geometry.fill",
      "stylers": [
        {
          "color": "#3e3e3e"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "landscape.man_made",
      "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
      "stylers": [
        {
          "color": "#808080"
        },
        {
          "visibility": "on"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "landscape.natural",
      "elementType": "geometry.fill",
      "stylers": [
        {
          "color": "#4d583c"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "landscape.natural.terrain",
      "elementType": "geometry.fill",
      "stylers": [
        {
          "color": "#404633"
        },
        {
          "visibility": "on"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "poi",
      "elementType": "geometry.fill",
      "stylers": [
        {
          "visibility": "off"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "poi",
      "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
      "stylers": [
        {
          "color": "#808080"
        },
        {
          "visibility": "on"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "poi.park",
      "elementType": "geometry.fill",
      "stylers": [
        {
          "color": "#495338"
        },
        {
          "visibility": "on"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "poi.sports_complex",
      "elementType": "geometry.fill",
      "stylers": [
        {
          "color": "#536041"
        },
        {
          "visibility": "on"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "road",
      "elementType": "geometry.fill",
      "stylers": [
        {
          "color": "#363636"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "road.arterial",
      "elementType": "geometry",
      "stylers": [
        {
          "color": "#363636"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "road.highway",
      "elementType": "geometry",
      "stylers": [
        {
          "color": "#252525"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "road.highway.controlled_access",
      "elementType": "geometry",
      "stylers": [
        {
          "color": "#252525"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "transit.line",
      "elementType": "geometry.fill",
      "stylers": [
        {
          "color": "#363636"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "transit.station",
      "elementType": "geometry",
      "stylers": [
        {
          "color": "#3e3e3e"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "water",
      "elementType": "geometry",
      "stylers": [
        {
          "color": "#204157"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "water",
      "elementType": "geometry.fill",
      "stylers": [
        {
          "color": "#204157"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "poi.attraction",
      "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
      "stylers": [
        {
          "visibility": "off"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "poi.government",
      "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
      "stylers": [
        {
          "visibility": "off"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "poi.business",
      "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
      "stylers": [
        {
          "visibility": "off"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "poi.medical",
      "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
      "stylers": [
        {
          "visibility": "off"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "poi.park",
      "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
      "stylers": [
        {
          "visibility": "off"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "poi.place_of_worship",
      "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
      "stylers": [
        {
          "visibility": "off"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "poi.school",
      "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
      "stylers": [
        {
          "visibility": "off"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "poi.sports_complex",
      "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
      "stylers": [
        {
          "visibility": "off"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "poi.attraction",
      "stylers": [
        {
          "visibility": "on"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "poi.government",
      "stylers": [
        {
          "visibility": "on"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "poi.business",
      "stylers": [
        {
          "visibility": "on"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "poi.medical",
      "stylers": [
        {
          "visibility": "on"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "poi.place_of_worship",
      "stylers": [
        {
          "visibility": "on"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "poi.park",
      "stylers": [
        {
          "visibility": "on"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "poi.school",
      "stylers": [
        {
          "visibility": "on"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "poi.sports_complex",
      "stylers": [
        {
          "visibility": "on"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

Comment: **What** are you trying to achieve? Might be a good idea to mention that when you ask a question!

Comment: @MrUpsidown Thanks for pointing out. I have made it clear now.

Comment: Not saying this is the issue... your JSON holds unnecessary data. You first set `labels.text.stroke` visibility to `off` (that means ALL labels text strokes for ALL feature types). Then later you set the same `elementType` to `off` for specific features (`poi.place_of_worship`, `poi.school`, etc.) which is redundant as you already set it to `off` for all feature types...

Comment: Agree. I tried that already, didn't work. So tried adding for specific features in the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

There must be an issue with the order of some elements in the JSON you posted. And as I said in my comment, there are some unnecessary lines in there as well that you should probably remove.

Importing the JSON in the tool you mentioned and exporting it again fixed the issue.

```js
var map;

function initialize() {

  var customStyle = [{
      "elementType": "geometry",
      "stylers": [{
        "color": "#3e3e3e"
      }]
    },
    {
      "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
      "stylers": [{
        "visibility": "off"
      }]
    },
    {
      "elementType": "labels.icon",
      "stylers": [{
        "visibility": "off"
      }]
    },
    {
      "elementType": "labels.text",
      "stylers": [{
        "color": "#808080"
      }]
    },
    {
      "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
      "stylers": [{
        "visibility": "off"
      }]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "administrative.land_parcel",
      "stylers": [{
        "visibility": "off"
      }]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "landscape.man_made",
      "elementType": "geometry.fill",
      "stylers": [{
        "color": "#3e3e3e"
      }]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "landscape.man_made",
      "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
      "stylers": [{
          "color": "#808080"
        },
        {
          "visibility": "on"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "landscape.natural",
      "elementType": "geometry.fill",
      "stylers": [{
        "color": "#4d583c"
      }]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "landscape.natural.terrain",
      "elementType": "geometry.fill",
      "stylers": [{
          "color": "#404633"
        },
        {
          "visibility": "on"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "poi",
      "elementType": "geometry.fill",
      "stylers": [{
        "visibility": "off"
      }]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "poi",
      "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
      "stylers": [{
          "color": "#808080"
        },
        {
          "visibility": "on"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "poi.attraction",
      "stylers": [{
        "visibility": "on"
      }]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "poi.attraction",
      "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
      "stylers": [{
        "visibility": "off"
      }]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "poi.business",
      "stylers": [{
        "visibility": "on"
      }]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "poi.business",
      "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
      "stylers": [{
        "visibility": "off"
      }]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "poi.government",
      "stylers": [{
        "visibility": "on"
      }]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "poi.government",
      "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
      "stylers": [{
        "visibility": "off"
      }]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "poi.medical",
      "stylers": [{
        "visibility": "on"
      }]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "poi.medical",
      "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
      "stylers": [{
        "visibility": "off"
      }]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "poi.park",
      "stylers": [{
        "visibility": "on"
      }]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "poi.park",
      "elementType": "geometry.fill",
      "stylers": [{
          "color": "#495338"
        },
        {
          "visibility": "on"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "poi.park",
      "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
      "stylers": [{
        "visibility": "off"
      }]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "poi.place_of_worship",
      "stylers": [{
        "visibility": "on"
      }]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "poi.place_of_worship",
      "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
      "stylers": [{
        "visibility": "off"
      }]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "poi.school",
      "stylers": [{
        "visibility": "on"
      }]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "poi.school",
      "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
      "stylers": [{
        "visibility": "off"
      }]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "poi.sports_complex",
      "stylers": [{
        "visibility": "on"
      }]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "poi.sports_complex",
      "elementType": "geometry.fill",
      "stylers": [{
          "color": "#536041"
        },
        {
          "visibility": "on"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "poi.sports_complex",
      "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
      "stylers": [{
        "visibility": "off"
      }]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "road",
      "elementType": "geometry.fill",
      "stylers": [{
        "color": "#363636"
      }]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "road.arterial",
      "elementType": "geometry",
      "stylers": [{
        "color": "#363636"
      }]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "road.highway",
      "elementType": "geometry",
      "stylers": [{
        "color": "#252525"
      }]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "road.highway.controlled_access",
      "elementType": "geometry",
      "stylers": [{
        "color": "#252525"
      }]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "transit.line",
      "elementType": "geometry.fill",
      "stylers": [{
        "color": "#363636"
      }]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "transit.station",
      "elementType": "geometry",
      "stylers": [{
        "color": "#3e3e3e"
      }]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "water",
      "elementType": "geometry",
      "stylers": [{
        "color": "#204157"
      }]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "water",
      "elementType": "geometry.fill",
      "stylers": [{
        "color": "#204157"
      }]
    }
  ];

  var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(59.32522, 18.07002),
    zoom: 10,
    styles: customStyle
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
}

initialize();
```

```css
#map-canvas {
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="map-canvas"></div>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
```

Comment: I understand that this works. This is kind of a workaround. But I want to know the reason behind the differences. Is there any separate rule/order in the documentation to be followed when applying the styles ?

Comment: I don't know what conflicts with what (except that removing all the POI stuff you added works as expected). All the rules that you stuffed in that JSON can be questioned as we don't know what else you want to achieve than *I want to disable the stroke effect for labels!!!*. And to answer that: set `labels.text.stroke` visibility off. Try to define again what you want and rebuild your styles from scratch. This *should* remove any unwanted/unneeded/conflicting rule.